# OneSignal: Android app craches when notification received

Tags: java, android, notifications, crash, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal to send push notifications to my Android app. I have added nothing special to the code of the app, just completed their basic setup, i.e. - addied their implementaion in build.gradle and created an ApplicationClass. It's all done exactly as their docs.

This is my ApplicationClass.java:

```
package com.ananya.brokenhearts;

import android.app.Application;
import com.onesignal.OSNotification;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class ApplicationClass extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
    }

}
```

Now, whenever I'm sending a notification through my dashboard and my app's in the foreground, it crashes. I have implemented Google Firebase Crashlytics which show the error to me as:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
No static method zzc(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzs; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzs; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzs' appears in /data/app/com.ananya.brokenhearts-VRiRdquDLM8iTGbzmELvkg==/base.apk)
```

What does the error mean and how can I stop this crash?

Comment: Please paste your build.gradle file

Comment: Never mind. I used the latest plugin about 2 days ago, which fixed the issue. The problem was with the previous version of the plugin which was the latest one at the time I installed it in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I updated OneSignal plugin to version 0.11.2 in `app/build.gradle` and my application stopped crashing:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.11.2'
}
```